# Установка драйвера OpenCL внутри Docker

Tags: linux, docker, драйвер

Для видеокарты AMD понадобилось установить драйвер OpenCL — [ROCm](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/). В описании говорится, что поддерживаются Ubuntu 18.04.5, Ubuntu 20.04.1 и другие дистрибутивы. Также, если верно понимаю, в системе должно быть ядро определённой версии.

Возможно ли, имея Debian bullseye с вручную скомпилированным ядром 5.4.62 в качестве хоста и Ubuntu в контейнере Docker, завести эти драйвера? Что при этом надо учесть? При попытке установить `rocm-dkms` в Debian возникает конфликт зависимостей.

Comment: с помощью программы *docker* можно всего лишь запустить какой-нибудь пользовательский процесс. отдельного экземпляра программы *linux* при этом не создаётся. так что все упоминания программы *docker* можете смело из вопроса удалить, а сосредоточиться на сборке модуля для вашей версии программы *linux*.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, понял, спасибо!